# Iterating quickly through Outlook appointment items

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar, iteration

I've written a macro which iterates through a users calendar and makes modifications to entries that fufil a certain critera.

The problem is that when the calendar is very big, this takes a long time to do. I don't seem to be able to filter the appointments because `oAppointmentItems` seems to store entries as they were created - which is not necessarily the same order as when they start.

The code I'm using is this:

```
Dim oOL As New Outlook.Application
Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oAppointments As Object
Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set oNS = oOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

For Each oAppointmentItem In oAppointments.Items

    DoEvents
    ' Something here
Next

Set oAppointmentItem = Nothing
Set oAppointments = Nothing
Set oNS = Nothing
Set oOL = Nothing
```

Short of removing the `DoEvents` (which only means that Outlook appears to lock up to the user) is there any way I can speed this up by applying some kind of filter? For example, appointments which start in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Restrict to filter. Note that dates are in the format month, day, year and that they are filtered as strings, even though stored as dates:

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olRecItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
strFilter = "[DueDate] > '1/15/2009'"
Set olFilterRecItems = olRecItems.Items.Restrict(strFilter)


For i = 1 To olFilterRecItems.Count
  <...>
```

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220369.aspx

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I was looking for today! This has saved me so much trouble. One thing I notice though is that I can't get it to work with a date filter using =, and it's hard to get an exact date (seems to depend on whether they're a date or a date/time in Outlook). Like > Date - 1 day and < Date will return one with just Date, whereas Date > Date And Date < Date + 1 day will return the items with Date/Time

Comment: Using early binding in VBA, how should olRecItems be DIM'd ? (Outlook.???). Thanks..

Comment: @iDevlop as  Outlook.MAPIFolder AFAIK.

Comment: For future readers, you can get the object type for early binding by calling the `TypeName` function on the variable once you've assigned it:

`Dim olRecItems`
`Set olRecItems = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)`
`Debug.Print TypeName(olRecItems)`

This prints `MAPIFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey couldn't get tasks to work but this seem to work on appointments 
[full explaination](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867729.aspx)

```
Dim myStart As Date
Dim myEnd As Date

myStart = Date
myEnd = DateAdd("d", 30, myStart)

Debug.Print "Start:", myStart
Debug.Print "End:", myEnd

'Construct filter for the next 30-day date range
strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & _
Format$(myStart, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") _
& "' AND [End] <= '" & _
Format$(myEnd, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") & "'"
'Check the restriction string
Debug.Print strRestriction

Const olFolderCalendar = 9
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set oCalendar = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)

Set oItems = oCalendar.items
oItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
' oItems.Sort "[Start]" ' commented out  worked for me.. 
'Restrict the Items collection for the 30-day date range
Set oItemsInDateRange = oItems.Restrict(strRestriction)
Debug.Print oItemsInDateRange.Count
```